# Laravel DB query builder left join with related counts

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I am new in Laravel and facing an issue with the DB query builder.
I want to fetch all the records from users table and want to count related wishlists in wishlists table. Here is my query.

```
select `users`.*, count(wishlists.id) as wishlists_count from `users` left join `wishlists` on `users`.`id` = `wishlists`.`uid` where `users`.`status` = 1 group by `wishlists`.`id`
```

I want to do it with laravel query builder. Here is what I am trying.

```
 $leads = DB::table('users')
            ->selectRaw('users.*', 'count(wishlists.id) as wishlists_count')
            ->leftJoin('wishlists', 'users.id', '=', 'wishlists.uid')
            ->where('users.status',1)
            ->groupBy('wishlists.id')
            ->get();
```

It is showing this error.

> Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw()
>   must be of the type array, string given.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions), the second argument to `selectRaw()` is an optional array of bindings.

However, you can achieve what you are looking for with a combination of `select()` and `DB::raw()`

```
$leads = DB::table('users')
   ->select('users.*', DB::raw('count(wishlists.id) as wishlists_count'))
   ->leftJoin('wishlists', 'users.id', '=', 'wishlists.uid')
   ->where('users.status',1)
   ->groupBy('wishlists.uid')
   ->get();
```

Edit: The above answer is wrong. I would consider the following alternatives instead.

Either you could achieve it with a Sub-Query with something like the following:

```
$wishlist = Wishlist::select(DB::raw('count(wishlists.id)'))
    ->whereColumn('uid', 'users.id')
    ->getQuery();

$users = User::select('users.*')
    ->selectSub($wishlist, 'wishlists_count')
    ->get();
```

Or with a much easier way (assuming you have a `wishlists` relationship set up)

```
Users::withCount('wishlists')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user->wishlists_count; 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it had also thrown an error, then disabled strict from database.php file and now it is working fine.

Comment: Edited my answer with 2 alternative solutions. I'd advise against turning off strict.